# Как получить данные из таблицы SQL в случайном порядке?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Есть таблица в БД. Как с помощью sqlalchemy получить все значения из таблицы в случайном порядке?

Comment: Какая БД используется? https://stackoverflow.com/a/60815/10941639

Answer (score 0):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
db_connection = 'mysql+pymysql://test:test@localhost/test_base'
conn = create_engine(db_connection)
response=conn.execute('SELECT * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY RAND()')
```